# focus on required field in another tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have built a form which is seperated across 3 tabs and within this form are  required fields.

On submit the html5 validation catches the errors if on the current tab, however I would like to use a bit of jquery to focus back on the correct tab and input field that has not been filled in and display an alert box. Im not sure if this is possible..

There is only 1 form on the page.

```
$('#btt_salva').click(function () {
$('input:invalid').each(function () {
    alert("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
    // Find the tab-pane that this element is inside, and get the id
    var $closest = $(this).closest('.tab-pane');

    var id = $closest.attr('id');


    // Find the link that corresponds to the pane and have it show
    $('.nav a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');

    // Only want to do it once

});
```

});

i use this javascript function and it works with required TEXT field but not with combo box(select).

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. And if you show your code, you might even get more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'select' element selector for combo box(select).

```
$('#btt_salva').click(function () {
    var invalidInputs = $('input:invalid, select:invalid');
    if(invalidInputs.length > 0){
        alert("aaaaaaaaaaaa");
        var invalidInput = $(invalidInputs[0]);
        var $closest = invalidInput.closest('.tab-pane');
        var id = $closest.attr('id');
        $('.nav a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```